# Refresh DataGridView after inserting values

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have established connection and inserted values into the table.

However, I am not sure the best method to refresh the DataGridview as the values have been inserted after click button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
   {             
      string theText = makeTextBox.Text;
      string theText2 = modelTextBox.Text;
                
      var value = Convert.ToInt32(yearTextBox.Text);      
      int i = 6;
      cnn.Open();
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = cnn;
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cars(Make,Model,Year) VALUES(@Make,@Model,@Year)";
      cmd.Prepare();

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", theText);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", theText2);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", value);
                
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   {
}

      dataGridView1.DataSource = carsBindingSource;
      dataGridView1.Refresh();

      cnn.Close();

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vokCq.png)

EDIT:

here is the code with the working solution of rebinding the datasource and then it will update:

````
        {
            string theText = textBox1.Text;
            string theText2 = textBox2.Text;

            var value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

            int i = 6;
            cnn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cars(Make,Model,Year) VALUES(@Make,@Model,@Year)";
            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", theText);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", theText2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            {
            }








            cnn.Close();

            carsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            carsBindingSource.DataSource = carsTableAdapter.GetData();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = carsBindingSource;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: The code appears to update/insert the data base with the new values, however, where is the code updating/inserting the new values into the `carsBindingSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the part where the `carsBindingSource` variable is initialized with data. From your limited code, it should be noted that… if you add/insert a new row into the table in the data base, then this is NOT going to automatically update the `carsBindingSource.`

It is unknown “what” is used as a `DataSource` to the `carsBindingSource.` OR, how this data source is populated. I will assume the `DataSource` to the `BindingSource` is a `DataTable` and that somewhere in the code it is getting this `DataTable` from a query to the data base. If this process is not already in a single method that returns a `DataTable`, then, I recommend you create one, and it may look something like…

```
private DataTable GetCarsDT() {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  string connString = "Server = localhost; Database = CarsDB; Trusted_Connection = True;";
  try {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand()) {
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Cars";
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) {
          da.Fill(ds, "Cars");
          return ds.Tables[0];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("DBError:" + ex.Message);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Above will return a `DataTable` with three (3) columns, Make, Model and Year. This `DataTable` is used as a `DataSource` to the `BindingSource`… `carsBindingBource.`

Now in the `button1_Click` event, the code inserts the new values into the data base. However, the `carsBindingSource` will still contain the data “before” the new items were added to the DB. Therefore, we can simply use the method above to “update” the `carsBindingSource` after the new items are added to the DB.

Note: you can go two routs here, 1) as described above, simply update “all” the data in the binding source… OR … 2) after updating the new items into the data base, you can also add the new items to the binding source’s data source… i.e. its `DataTable`. Either way will work and unless there is a large amount of data, I do not think one way would be preferred over the other.

Below shows what is described above. Note, the commented code adds the new items directly to the `DataTable.` You can use either one but obviously not both.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string connString = "Server = localhost; Database = CarsDB; Trusted_Connection = True;";
  try {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand()) {
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cars(Make,Model,Year) VALUES(@Make,@Model,@Year)";
        command.Parameters.Add("@Make", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = makeTextBox.Text.Trim();
        command.Parameters.Add("@Model", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = modelTextBox.Text.Trim();
        int.TryParse(yearTextBox.Text.Trim(), out int year);
        command.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = year;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        carsBindingSource.DataSource = GetCarsDT();
        //DataTable dt = (DataTable)carsBindingSource.DataSource;
        //dt.Rows.Add(makeTextBox.Text.Trim(), modelTextBox.Text.Trim(), year);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("DBError:" + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Putting all this together…

```
BindingSource carsBindingSource;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  carsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
  carsBindingSource.DataSource = GetCarsDT();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = carsBindingSource;
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I can find the method I think youre talking about. but it will need to be in the button click event to reload the datagridview when i click the button correct?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by… _”but it will need to be in the button click event”_ … ? The method (itself) does not “need” to be "in" the button click event, but you need to “Call” the method from the button click event… in my example… like…`carsBindingSource.DataSource = GetCarsDT();`

Comment: In your posted code, you re-set the grids data source to the `carsBindingSource`, however, your code never “updates” that binding source. In other words, the two lines of code you have… `dataGridView1.DataSource = carsBindingSource;  dataGridView1.Refresh();` accomplish nothing since the binding source has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible. You may need to create a separate button to submit and then refresh the data